# pandas apply function with multiple condition?

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

if i want to apply lambda with multiple condition how should I do it?

```
df.train.age.apply(lambda x:0 (if x>=0 and x<500))
```

or is there much better methods?

Comment: I strongly suggest using the square bracket syntax for selecting columns. Just in this tiny example, it already isn’t clear what’s going on. Can you share what your DataFrame looks like?

Comment: I would read make a function `def mx(x):
    j=[]
    if x>=0:
     j.append(x)
     if j[0] < 500:
         print(j[0])
         return j[0]
    if x >= 500 or x <0:
     print(x,'bad') 
            
mx(0)       
# is zero

mx(500)
#bad 500

mx(-1)
#-1`

Answer (score 3):

create a mask and select from your array with the mask ... only apply to the result

```
mask = (df.train.age >=0) & (df.train.age < 500)
df.train.age[mask].apply(something)
```

if you just need to set the ones that dont match to zero thats even easier

```
df.train.age[~mask] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax needs to have an else:

```
df.train.age.apply(lambda x:0 if x>=0 and x<500 else 0)
```

This is a good way to do it

Answer (score 0):

The same can be obtained without using `apply`, but using `np.where` as below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age' : [-10,10,20,30,40,100,110]
})
df['age'] = np.where((df['age'] >= 100) | (df['age'] < 0), 0, df['age'])
df
```

If you have any confusion in using the above code, Please post your sample dataframe. I'll update my answer.