# Regular expression for identifying only special characters, if special character is between/behind/front of words then ignore

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a situation where I need to identify if there are only special characters in a pandas column,
i.e; if any rows has values like ?,##,<>&^%, then it should be identified
also if these special characters are between words like ">=50k","50+","value-words"
then nothing should be done,

I have implemented two regexes:

```
1. special_characters = re.compile(r'[!@#$%^&()_{}[\]:;<>,?~\|?]+')
```

this one identifies if theres a special character only

```
2. special_character_between_words = re.compile(r'(?<=\w)[/?#*^\-$]+(?=\w)|^[/?#*^\-$]+|[/#*^\-$]+$')
```

this one identifies special between words

while checking in pandas df

I am using

```
only_special_char_bool = df['col'].astype(str).str.contains.(special_characters).any()

special_chars_bw_words = df['col'].astype(str).str.contains.(special_character_between_words).any()

if only_special_char_bool:
    df['col']=df['col'].astype(str).replace(special_characters,'',regex=True)
elif special_chars_bw_words:
    pass
```

issue here is: it is identifying the special characters between words and replacing them with '' like ">=50k" is changed into "50k", what should have been done that if ">=50k" is identified then it should be kept as it is and if only special characters are identified then it should be replaced with empty string

Comment: read notice : [mre]

Comment: why dont you append a column capturing whether the conditions apply. then only apply the first expression if the second is not fulfilled. Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341265/pandas-apply-function-with-multiple-condition

Comment: The problem with `"...if any rows has values like ?,##,<>&^%"` is that "like" suggests your list is not exhaustive but you provide no indication of what other characters should be included. I suggest you instead write "...if any row contains any character in the string `'?,##,<>&^%'"`. That  should make it  unambiguous .  For the purpose of the question it's not important that the string contains every character of interest as you can adapt answers as needed. Also, I suggest avoiding the expression "special characters" as the term is not defined.

Comment: Even simpler: `df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'^[\W_]+$', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Your code can't work as is. `only_special_char_bool` will be true any time that `special_chars_bw_words` is true, so only the first statement of your `if` block will be executed, which will delete all special characters, wherever they occur. What you need to do is *only* replace special characters when they are *all* that occurs in a value:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'^[!@#$%^&()_{}[\]:;<>,?~\|?]+$', '', regex=True)
```

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ["&^#%$&!^", ">=50k", "50+", "value-words", "(@#)@"] })
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'^[!@#$%^&()_{}[\]:;<>,?~\|?]+$', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
           col
0
1        >=50k
2          50+
3  value-words
4
```